# Android. Navigation drawer. Backstack issues in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-fragmentactivity, back-stack

I am trying to implement app with navigation drawer. 
I created application on Eclipse. 
This is default(or template) navigation drawer application.
MainActivity has root FrameLayout which includes different fragments at different times.
By default, it contains fragment A. 
When item B will be chosen from navigation drawer, it will replace fragment A to fragment B.

MainActivity:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentB);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

FragmentB is root fragment for fragmentB2, FragmentB3 etc.
I thought that in this way, it will be easier to save fragments state.
It is saving fragment state only for FragmentB2.

FragmentA(root A) onCreateView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Inflate the layout for this fragment */
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_balance_root, container,
            false);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.balance_root_frame, MainActivity.balanceMainFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

    return view;
}
```

FragmentA2 OnCreateView():

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_balance_main,
            container, false);
    return rootView;
```

FragmentB(root B) onCreateView():

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.tariffs_root_frame, MainActivity.tariffsMainFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

FragmentB2:

```
private static void goToTariffInfo() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.tariffs_root_frame, new TariffsInfoFragment());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Fragment B3:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tariffs_info,
        container, false);
return rootView;
```

I have many questions, but they are related to each other.
1. How to avoid saving root fragment in backstack? 
When I press back button on Fragment A2 it goes to A1 which is blank.
I have tried to remove addToBackStack from MainActivity. This caused to quit on only one press back button.
I have tried to remove addToBackStack from FragmentA. No effect.

2.How to set seperate backstack for different collections of fragments?
For example: Navigation drawer includes 2 items: ItemA and ItemB.
Each item can be considered as one section.
FragmenA->FragmentA2->FragmentA3
FragmentB->FragmentB2->FragmentB3
But in my situation, when I click on back button on Fragment B2, somehow app goes back to Fragment A2(which previously was opened)
Even on Fragment B3, back button causes to go to Fragment A2.
How to solve these problems?